# How to proof that distinct "recursive geometrical constructions" converge to the same object?

Tags: geometric-construction, tiling

It seems like a topological isomorphism problem ... I'm starting with an "intuitive isomorphism recognition" of 3 objects, which are *defined by geometric construction*. I'm looking for a formalization sketch, if there is no obvious solution to proof the isomorphism.

The objects to be compared are [aperiodic tilings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperiodic_tiling) of dominoes, and they exhibit the behavior of [domino tiling patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domino_tiling). Each object is using a different construction technique:

- **Obj1** is knowed as was "[table tiling](https://tilings.math.uni-bielefeld.de/substitution/domino/)" builded by geometric [cut-and-project](https://tilings.math.uni-bielefeld.de/glossary/cut-and-project/). It is also in described [this paper](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1608/1608.07165.pdf) , as a classical domino tiling.
- **Obj2** is a obtained from a [Hilbert curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve) transformation, [described here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/357117/153024) by merging adjacent cells with the rule $j = \lceil{i/2} \rceil$.
- **Obj3** can be named here as "Munkres's fractal" because we can found at "Theorem 44.1" into [this Munkres's notes](https://faculty.etsu.edu/gardnerr/5357/notes/Munkres-44.pdf).

In the initial construction process of each object, they are different and is difficult to check similarities. They are all recursive processes and quickly "converge" to the same pattern, that I am supposing that is also an isomorphism. The question can be splitted into two "how to" parts.

**How to:**

1. **Formalize all the construction processes in the same framework?**
   That is, what the better theory/approach to describe all them with the same language?
2. **Proof that all converge  to the same**, where I am supposing that they are isomorphic.

... For example expressing all objects by [L-system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system) models, them showing that, by adjusting parameters and rule names, they are equivalent models.

---

### The objects

Objcts 1 and 2:
[image]

and **Obj3**:
[image]